# can't find this NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I keep getting a `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo... Caused by a NullPointerException at findViewById` and i can't find out why it is throwing it. i have my elements id's set correctly in my `main.xml` and i have tried commenting out each line around where it is throwing to see which line is faulty but to get it to run w/o any force closes i have to comment out all the functionality of the program. here is my activity:

```
package fsg.dev.test.checkboxtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class checkBoxTest extends Activity {
    private CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    //private SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    private View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
            changeColor();
        }
    });
}

private void changeColor(){
    if(checkbox.isChecked()){
        view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Blue);
        //view.setAlpha(.25);
    }
    else if(!checkbox.isChecked()){
        view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.White);
    }
}
```

}

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="fsg.dev.test.checkboxtest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".checkBoxTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and finally my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<CheckBox 
    android:text="Background Color" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:checked="false"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox">
</CheckBox>
<SeekBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >
</SeekBar>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:id="@+id/background">
</View>
</LinearLayout>
```

if anyone could help me narrow this down that would be excellent.

Comment: Can you put the logcat message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `findViewById` only after `setContentView`:

```
....
public class checkBoxTest extends Activity {
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    private View view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
            changeColor();
        }
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call findViewById in your onCreate() method after you have called setContentView(R.layout.main) as your UI objects will not exist until after the XML has been inflated in to their respective Java objects.

Answer (score 1):

move your calls to findViewById into the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

This instantiation

```
private CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    //private SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    private View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);
```

Should come in the method of onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is  to set the Content of your activity , and then , you can get All views from that content , so replace your code with this :

```
public class checkBoxTest extends Activity {
    private CheckBox checkbox ;
    private View view ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//first , set the content of your activity
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Second, get yours Views 
     checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
     view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                changeColor();
            }
        });
    }
....
```